# Real life physics problem: Why is my desktop computer affected by my plasma ball?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, everyday-life, plasma-physics

Note: this is strictly a physics question, not meant to be an advertisement

I was running my desktop with a plasma ball on the side. The desktop has a touch screen enabled.
[image]

I started to notice that the screen began to behave erratically, shifting up and down, left and right. At first I thought it was some sort of strange glitch, or perhaps a virus, but the issue persisted and cannot be fixed until I decided to turn off the plasma ball at which point the screen turned normal.

Can someone elaborate on how the plasma ball may have interacted with the touch-enabled screen so it resulted in the erratic behavior on the screen that I saw?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_globe#Hazards

Comment: Does the effect decrease if you displace the plasma ball farther from the screen? Is the effect present if you use different kind of screen (no sensitivity to touching)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: plasma ball emits RF "noise". The touch screen is sensitive to noise (as it tries to detect the presence of your finger by detecting very tiny currents that appear between transparent electrodes as a result of the presence of your finger (which is dielectrically different than air ).

Hoping someone else will elaborate for you.